# Походження слова "кромка"?

Tags: етимологія, іменники

В українській мові є цікаве слово [кромка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0), яке часто старші люди вживають при вказуванні на частину(окраєць) хліба. Очевидно, що це слово є запозиченим, однак у [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) цього слова не знайшла. Тоді яке ж походження слова **кромка**?

Comment: Продублюю вам про всяк випадок: Пишу не про конкретно це ваше запитання, а загалом. Будь ласка, приймайте (✓) відповіді на запитання трохи повільніше (часто бачив, як ви приймаєте першу ж відповідь десь протягом години після її появи). Маю припущення, що коли користувачі бачать «вже розв'язане» питання, вони частково втрачають ентузіазм до написання власної відповіді, а було б добре мати по декілька відповідей (декілька кутів зору) на кожне запитання (це заохочується політикою цього сайту, і наша спільнота таку політику підтримує).

Comment: Тобто приймайте, будь ласка, відповідь лише тоді, коли вважаєте, що вона справді неперевершена, а в решті випадків давайте пару діб на написання іншими користувачами інших відповідей

Comment: Візьму всі побажання до уваги. Дякую!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Найімовірніше, що слово кромка утворене із слова "крома". Далі - звертаємось у той же [ЕСУМ, т. 3, с. 102](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=102) і знаходимо:

> **[крома] - Ж;­** р. [крома] «край, бік чогось», кромка «край чогось; вузька смужка по краю тканини», п. **kromka «скибка, шматок»**, вл. kroma «край, рант, борт; кромка; **пола б. krumka «окраєць хліба**»;- псл. kroma «обріза­ний край чогось»;-очевидно, спорід­нене з лит. krimsti «гризти»; **припущення про походження від нім. Krume «м'якушка»**.

***Отже, це слово у значенні "окраєць хліба" побутує у багатьох мовах, зокрема є припущення про походження від нім. Krume «м'якушка».***